# Pandas named aggregation syntax throws error TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I have a pandas dataframe as follows

```
aa = pd.DataFrame({
'x': range(0, 5),
'g1': [1,1,2,2,1]})
```

when I use unnamed aggregation I got the results as expected

```
xx = aa.groupby('g1').agg({'x' : 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

But when I change the syntax to the named aggregation

```
xx = aa.groupby('g1').agg(xsum=('x', 'sum')).reset_index()
```

I got the following error message

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'

Not sure where I went wrong..

Answer (score 2):

You error lies somewhere else, there is no conversion to int in you code.

The provided snippet works fine, as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
aa = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(0, 5),
                   'g1': [1,1,2,2,1]})
aa.groupby('g1').agg(xsum=('x', 'sum')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   g1  xsum
0   1     5
1   2     5
```